# Jersey ReST webservice returning a File

Tags: java, file-io, jersey

I've found several good examples of how to return a File / OutputStream from a ReSTful Jersey webservice, but it appears that they all ultimately create a File on the file system.  My problem is that I don't want to leave these files lingering around on the machine.  Is there a way for me to clean-up once the service sends the response to the client without having to have some backend process monitoring the file system for these Files?

Comment: How about not creating the file and using a http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html object?

Comment: I'm confused. What is it that you're trying to return? Data from a file? Data from somewhere else? What are these "lingering files"?

Comment: I'm trying to return a File as an attachment to the client (browser).  I'm using the _Content-Disposition_ HTTP header to place the file as an attachment, but once my ReST resource has completed the return, the file is still on the application server's file system.

Answer (score 0):

You could just return the file in base64, process and forget.